# Outlook won't open after closing

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have a user that when he closes outlook, it will not reopen unless the user restarts the computer.  I checked task manager when reopening outlook, while outlook seems to start and show up in the details list, it does not open.
If the user restarts outlook then it works without issue until he either closes outlook or tries to reopen an email.  Then the user is unable to open either.
We are using O365 with an E3 subscription and Windows 10

Comment: I don't think this is a common problem. Perhaps fully uninstall Outlook (Office) and remove the Outlook email profile. Restart, install Office and patch. Make a new Outlook profile and test.

Comment: Do you think that making a new profile would help before uninstalling office?

Comment: You can try that and see if that works.

Comment: So simply (opening, closing, and reopening) an email causes this problem? I would just reimage the system

Comment: >> "I checked task manager when reopening outlook, while outlook seems to start and show up in the details list, it does not open."

Can you see the Outlook icon show up in the system tray?
Have you tried holding down ALT and hit Tab to see if you are able to see the Outlook window? 
Also, give it a shot by opening Outlook in safe mode(Win+R, type "outlook /safe", press Enter.)

Answer (score 0):

Using the repair/modify and doing an online repair will often fix most of the issues I have with office software. If that doesn't work, Microsoft also provides a diagnostic tool that has fixed some of the peskier issues for me. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-the-microsoft-support-and-recovery-assistant-e90bb691-c2a7-4697-a94f-88836856c72f#ID0ED6=Outlook